# (mainActifity)fragment --> new fragment passing object from list using an interface

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have trouble with 2 things.

1. Somehow I cannot make my interface `onClickListener` work.
2. After I got the first problem solved, I have not an idea about how to start `fragmentB` to display the book (`fragmentA` has a `RecycleView` with books)

Did I check and tried solutions on stack/google?

Yes, I did, have been struggling with these problems for the last 2 days.
Some codes are old, some I cannot figure out how to implement it in my code, as I am still a beginner.

`FragmentA(mangasSearch)` is part of `MainActivity` (not sure if you want to see the code of `MainActivity`)

`FragmentB` will be a new Fragment that when pressed back, will be destroyed and get back to `fragmentA`

Here is my `RecycleView`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import Classes.Manga;

public class MyAdapterRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapterRecyclerView.MyViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Manga> mDataSet;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapterRecyclerView(ArrayList<Manga> dataSet, Context context) {
        mDataSet = dataSet;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycleview_item, parent, false);
        //  final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);//, communicator);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Picasso.get().load(mDataSet.get(position).getPosterPicture()).into(holder.imageviewBookCover);
        holder.tvBookTitle.setText("This is book nr: " + position + " and title " + mDataSet.get(position).getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataSet.size();
    }


    private static OnMangaBookClickListener onMangaBookClickListener;

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public ImageView imageviewBookCover;
        public TextView tvBookTitle;
        OnMangaBookClickListener onMangaBookClickListener;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageviewBookCover = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_bookcover);
            tvBookTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_booktitle);

            itemView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) onMangaBookClickListener);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onMangaBookClickListener.onMangaBookClick(getAdapterPosition(), view);
        }
    }

    public void setOnMangaBookClickListener(OnMangaBookClickListener onMangaBookClickListener) {
        MyAdapterRecyclerView.onMangaBookClickListener = onMangaBookClickListener;
    }

    public interface OnMangaBookClickListener {
        void onMangaBookClick(int position, View view);
    }
}
```

Here I made the interface, so I call it on `fragmentA` and create `FragmentB`.

Here is `fragmentA` code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import Classes.JsonHandling;
import Classes.Manga;

public class MangasSearchFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MyAdapterRecyclerView mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private Bundle results;
    private ArrayList<Manga> mangaTempList;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mangas_to_search, container, false);
        Context context = getActivity();
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_manga_book);
        mangaTempList = new JsonHandling(context).getMangaBookJson();

        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // use a linear layout manager
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 3));

        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        mAdapter = new MyAdapterRecyclerView(mangaTempList, context);

        mAdapter.setOnMangaBookClickListener(new MyAdapterRecyclerView.OnMangaBookClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMangaBookClick(int position, View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "WHAT?!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK for onClickListener you create an Interface in your adapter and make the Fragment implements it and pass it to the adapter constructor f.e

```
public class MyAdapterRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapterRecyclerView.MyViewHolder> {
......
    OnItemInteractListener mListner;
    public MyAdapterRecyclerView(ArrayList<Manga> dataSet, OnItemInteractListener listener){
    this.mListner = listener;
    ......
    // your adapter code
    public interface OnItemInteractListener{
        void onItemInteract(int position);
    }
}
```

and in your fragment

```
public class MangasSearchFragment extends Fragment implements MyAdapterRecyclerView.OnItemInteractListener{
// this will automatically ask you to override the onItemIteract method where you'll display your toast or open your fragment 
....
// your fragment code 
mAdapter = new MyAdapterRecyclerView(mangaTempList, this); // pass the listener to adapter using this
```

this is basically how you communicate between adapter and fragment
you use that mListener variable in adapter whenever the user clicks on an item
and the easy way to listen to user click is inside onBindViewHolder method
using

```
viewHolder.YourView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.onItemInteract(position);
            }
        }
```

so the final code of yours should be like this
**MyAdapterRecyclerView**

```
public class MyAdapterRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapterRecyclerView.MyViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<Manga> mDataSet;
private Context context;
OnMangaBookClickListener mListener;
public MyAdapterRecyclerView(ArrayList<Manga> dataSet, OnMangaBookClickListener listener) {
    mDataSet = dataSet;
    this.mListener = listener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycleview_item, parent, false);
    //  final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    this.context = parent.getContext();
    return new MyViewHolder(view);//, communicator);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Picasso.get().load(mDataSet.get(position).getPosterPicture()).into(holder.imageviewBookCover);
    holder.tvBookTitle.setText("This is book nr: " + position + " and title " + mDataSet.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onMangaBookClick(position);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSet.size();
}


private static OnMangaBookClickListener onMangaBookClickListener;

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    public ImageView imageviewBookCover;
    public TextView tvBookTitle;
    
    public View itemView;
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.itemView = itemView;
        imageviewBookCover = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_bookcover);
        tvBookTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_booktitle);

    }

}

public interface OnMangaBookClickListener {
    void onMangaBookClick(int position);
    }
}
```

and for **MangasSearchFragment**

```
public class MangasSearchFragment extends Fragment implements  MyAdapterRecyclerView.OnMangaBookClickListener{

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private MyAdapterRecyclerView mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private Bundle results;
private ArrayList<Manga> mangaTempList;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mangas_to_search, container, false);
    Context context = getActivity();
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_manga_book);
    mangaTempList = new JsonHandling(context).getMangaBookJson();

    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 3));

    // specify an adapter (see also next example)
    mAdapter = new MyAdapterRecyclerView(mangaTempList, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onMangaBookClick(int position) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "item "+position, 

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }}
```

---

**Edit**
**That's for second part use that code where you're using Toast**

in FragmentA use this inside the onClickLisnter and pass the position ( or any data using bundle )

```
public class MangasSearchFragment extends Fragment implements  MyAdapterRecyclerView.OnMangaBookClickListener{

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private MyAdapterRecyclerView mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private Bundle results;
private ArrayList<Manga> mangaTempList;
int containerID = 0;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   containerID = container.getId();
   ... // your code 
 }
@Override
public void onMangaBookClick(int position) {

   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putInt("position", position);
   FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
   fragmentB.setArguments(bundle);
   getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
             .replace(containerID, fragmentB, "FragmentB")
             .addToBackStack(null)
             .commit();
   }}
```

and use getArguments() in FragmentB to retrieve the data

```
int position =  getArguments().getInt("position");
```

---

add this to Fragment

Comment: But the onClick is never called,  the What message in the toast is never shown...

Comment: I thought you said you solved that as you literally wrote  (After I got the first problem solved) :DD alright I'll alter my answer and mark as answer if it helps you ;)

Comment: it means when i solve that problem, ill have problem 2 :D

Comment: well I got you :DD you are using weird way of implementing onClickListener it should be way easier than that idk if I should fix your method or show you easier way :D

Comment: please show/teach me the easy way as i am totally lost :D

Comment: OnMangaBookClickListener listener; //private? shoudnt this 1 be private in the adapter?

Comment: and the listener, is not position needed, i can only send object if i want, correct?

Comment: and final question, container.getId   i get cannot resolve symbol 'container'

Comment: @cc2k yes private and without access modifier is kinda like private it gives default access.
you can pass whatever you want ideally you might want to pass the item like  mDataSet.get(position)

Comment: oh yes because the container is a variable inside onCreateView method 
you can declare a global variable let's say >>>  int containerID; <<<
and inside the onCreateView put 
 >>> containerID = container.getId(); <<<< 
and inside the onclick use containerID instead of container.getId()

Comment: getting some null on different parts, and dinner is ready will, debug later and will accept the answer when it works :)

Comment: alright xD I'll try to update the answer if still null you should probably give more info where's the null exception coming from xD

Comment: on mangaBook(frag B) i get traget must not be null with  ``` Picasso.get().load(manga.getPosterPicture()).into(mangaBookPosterCover); ``` atm i cant find the reason yet.

Comment: somehow all my TextViews and ImageViews are null...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218653/discussion-between-ahmed-nader-and-cc2k).

Comment: Reason for null, was wrong fragment called for layout :D